# Как выровнять блок внутри slick slider?

Tags: slider-slick.js

Есть проблема блок стоит не по центру из-за того, что его смещает последний видимый элемент. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужен пример кода. Но думаю дело в том, что просто элементы внутри слайдов нужно разместить по центру.

Для этого можно прописать стили для самих слайдов:

```
.slick-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```